# How to refresh a selected item on a custom menu click

Tags: content-editor, sheer-ui, ribbon, commands

I have a custom menu written to copy the item language version to another language.

**The current behavior is -** when I click on the menu it copies the current language version to another language version and don't reload or refresh the item. I have to re-click on the item to reload or refresh it. 
I want to trigger this by code so I wrote the code as below

```
     var copiedItem = _db.GetItem(item.ID, _targetLanguage);
            string load = string.Concat("item:load(id=", copiedItem.ID, ",language=", copiedItem.Language, ",version=", copiedItem.Version, ")");
            Context.ClientPage.SendMessage(this, load);
```

But I am getting the error as below -

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage..ctor() at Sitecore.Context.get_ClientPage() at PT.Framework.ItemCopy.Copying.CopyFromLanguage.AddVersionRecursiveCommand.StartProgressBar(Object[] contextParameters)
```

What I understood so far is that I cannot refresh the ClientPage from a custom command class. but then there should be some solution, right? if yes, then please help me to resolve this (it's already taken my half a day)

Thank you to all in advance.

Comment: Did you investigate the Context.ClientPage.ClientResponse Namespace?

Comment: Yes, It is Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer , is it correct? I think this is the issue then, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the Timer method with refresh option,

String refresh = String.Format("item:refreshchildren(id={0})", myItem.Parent.ID);
Sitecore.Context.ClientPage.ClientResponse.Timer(refresh, 2);

Comment: string refresh = string.Format("item:refresh(id={0})", args.Parameters["id"]); //worked when I use "item:refresh" instead off "item:refreshchildren". Thanks @Nizar